# TouchMove event end so fast in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, .net, swift, xamarin

I have created a canvas view like the below. When I apply it to a new project, it work correctly but  when I put it into my real project, I cannot draw a solid line. It's always being dashed (like the picture below). The first time, I thought it was an issue because I pushed too much screen until this drawable. But I was tried to disable UserInteraction of the previous view each time I push a new view in and it didnt work. Any help please!

```
public class CanvasView : UIView
{
    public CanvasView (CGRect frame) : base(frame)
    {
        this.drawPath = new CGPath();
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

    }


    private CGPoint touchLocation;
    private CGPoint previousTouchLocation;
    private CGPath drawPath;
    private bool fingerDraw;
    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews ();
        Layer.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
        Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.FromRGB (146, 146, 146).CGColor;
    }
    public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);
        UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
        this.fingerDraw = true;
        this.touchLocation = touch.LocationInView(this);
        this.previousTouchLocation = touch.PreviousLocationInView(this);

        this.SetNeedsDisplay();
    }
    public override void TouchesMoved (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesMoved (touches, evt);
        UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
        this.touchLocation = touch.LocationInView(this);
        this.previousTouchLocation = touch.PreviousLocationInView(this);

        this.SetNeedsDisplay();
    }

    public override void TouchesEnded (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesEnded (touches, evt);
        var alert = new UIAlertView () {
            Message = "Xui"
        };
        alert.AddButton("OK");
        alert.Show();
    }
    public override void Draw (CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);
        if (this.fingerDraw)
        {
            using (CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
            {
                context.SetStrokeColor(UIColor.Black.CGColor);
                context.SetLineWidth(1.5f);
                context.SetLineJoin(CGLineJoin.Round);
                context.SetLineCap(CGLineCap.Round);
                this.drawPath.MoveToPoint(this.previousTouchLocation);
                this.drawPath.AddLineToPoint(this.touchLocation);
                context.AddPath(this.drawPath);
                context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qANWu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the issue is not with `TouchesMoved`, it's with your drawing logic. When you call `SetNeedsDisplay()` it doesn't mean "draw now", it means "I have changes that need to be drawn, so be a dear and draw me when you can." This means that before the drawing is handled there are more touches coming in.

You'll have to either keep the previous point the same until you get a call to `Draw` or you'll have to put the points into a buffer and draw them all at the same time. I would do the first one since it's simpler.

Comment: but i dont know how does it work on another project? please give me more details!

Comment: I was tried to do as your suggestion but still like that :(